# php find number range of array

Tags: php

i have an array like this:

```
$d=array('good'=>10,'very good'=>20,'bad'=>1);
```

i want to find key from it when 13 number closest vlaue of array.

for example 16 close to 20 in `$d` array .

like result:

```
key:very good
value:20
```

Code

```
$d=array('good'=>10,'very good'=>20,'bad'=>1);

$find=13;
foreach(array_chunk($find, 5) as $val) {
    echo reset($val) . "-" . end($val);
}
```

sorry for my english.

Comment: Have you actually tried to solve this problem, or is this a `send me teh codez` question?

Comment: i tired to solved but i cant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not very pretty code, but I think it does what you want it to.

```
$d=array('good'=>10,'very good'=>20,'bad'=>1);

$closest = array('int' => -1, 'key' => null);
$find = 16;
foreach($d as $k=>$v) {
    if ($closest['int'] == -1) { $closest['int'] = abs($find-$v); $closest['key'] = $k; continue; }
    if (abs($find - $v) < $closest['int']) {
        $closest['int'] = abs($find-$v);
        $closest['key'] = $k;
    }
}

echo "key:".$closest['key']."
value:".$d[$closest['key']];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
$d = array('good' => 10,'very good' => 20,'bad' => 1);

vprintf("Find:%d, Closest: %d, Grade: %s\n",findClosest($d,13));
vprintf("Find:%d, Closest: %d, Grade: %s\n",findClosest($d,16));
```

Output

```
Find:13, Closest: 10, Grade: good
Find:16, Closest: 20, Grade: very good
```

Function Used

```
function findClosest($array, $find) {
    $map = array_map(function ($v) use($find) {
        return abs($v - $find);
    }, $array);
    asort($map);
    return array($find,$array[key($map)],key($map));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try code

```
$d = array('good'=>10,'very good'=>20,'bad'=>1);
$find=13;

$result = get_closest($d , $find);
echo $result;

function get_closest($array  = array(), $key){
     $new_arr = array();
     foreach($array AS $index=>$arr){
         if($key < $arr)  {
            $new_arr[$index] = $arr - $key;
         }
         else{
             $new_arr[$index] = $key - $arr;
         }
     }

     $min_val = min($new_arr);
     $res = array_search( $min_val , $new_arr);
     return $res;
   }
```

thanks

Answer (score -1):

you can use array_values function to get all values as $a, then you can sort $a.After sort you can find two numbers between $find, then you can compare those two numbers.